# Uncaught TypeError: vm.name is not a function

Tags: html, mithril.js

I am a new Frond-end developer learning "Mithril JS". I created sample login page using MVC Pattern. The login form is not working after console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: vm.name is not a function
```

How to resolve this issue?

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Mithril Js</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/todomvc-common/base.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="bower_components/mithril/mithril.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/todomvc-common/base.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="MitApp"></section>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/views/login.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/todos.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**App.Js** (create route map)

```
var app = app || {};

(function(window){
    'use strict';

    app.ENTER_KEY = 13;
    app.ESC_KEY = 27;

    m.route.mode = "hash";

    m.route(document.getElementById('MitApp'), '/', {
        "/":app,
        "/:filter":app
    });
})(window);
```

**Login Form**

```
var app = app || {};



app.view = function(ctrl){
    var vm = app;
    console.log(vm);
    return[m(".container", {style: {"margin-top": "55px"}}, [
            m(".col-md-4.col-md-offset-4", [
                m("h4", "Login"),
                m("form[action=''][enctype='multipart/form-data'][method='post']", [
                    m(".form-group", [
                        m("input.form-control[placeholder='Username'][type='name']", {value:vm.name(), onchange:m.writeAttr("value", vm.name)})
                    ]),
                    m(".form-group", [
                        m("input.form-control[placeholder='Password'][type='password']", {value:vm.password(), onchange:m.writeAttr("value",vm.password)})
                    ]),
                    m(".form-group", [
                        m("button.btn.btn-primary.pull-right[id='login'][type='submit']",{onclick:vm.submit.bind(vm)}, "Login")
                    ])
                ])
            ]),
            "\
"
        ])]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, your `app.view` function in your login form contains a reference to `vm.name`, but none of the code you've posted here defines what `vm.name` is. The second line of the function is `console.log(vm)` — so you should be able to open your browser console and see what `vm` is. I can see that `vm` is a reference to `app`, and by reading the rest of your code I can see the following references attached:

```
app.ENTER_KEY = 13;
app.ESC_KEY = 27;
app.view = function(){/**/}
```

As far as I can see, those are the only properties set on `app` / `vm`, but when I read the contents of the `app.view` function, I can see that it expects the following extra properties to be available:

```
vm.name
vm.password
vm.submit
```

`vm.name` and `vm.password` look like [`m.prop`s](http://mithril.js.org/mithril.prop.html), and `vm.submit` is obviously a function (it's clear what you expect it to do - log in the user - but I can't know how you expect to do that). So the way to make the `view` execute properly would be to define those properties. I'll define these in the same place you defined `app.ENTER_KEY` and `app.ESC_KEY` - in **App.js** - because that seems to be where you want to keep your model:

```
var app = app || {};

(function(window){
    'use strict';

    app.ENTER_KEY = 13;
    app.ESC_KEY = 27;

    // Define the extra properties needed for your view:
    app.name = m.prop( '' )
    app.password = m.prop( '' )

    app.submit = function(){
      // ...
    }

    m.route.mode = "hash";

    m.route(document.getElementById('MitApp'), '/', {
        "/":app,
        "/:filter":app
    });
})(window);
```